# How can I tell if my IP is static or assigned by DHCP on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, dhcp, ip

I don't know if my IP is static or assigned by DHCP. How can I find out which it is? I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Do you mean the IP on your computer or your internet-facing IP?

Comment: @Matt, local at first, but since you ask, I'd be interested in both answers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Run `ipconfig /all` in a cmd window; one of the lines will be labeled "DHCP Enabled".

Answer (score 8):

Go to the Network and Sharing Center (in control panel) and select "Change Adapter Settings" on the left.

From there double-click on your network adaptor and press the "Details" button.

You should see something like this:

[image]

You can then see if DHCP is enabled or not.

For your internet IP, the best way is to go to http://www.whatismyip.com and note down your IP.  Then go and reboot your router, and visit that site again and see if the IP is the same.

If it has changed you have a dynamic address.  If it's the same you may be static, or you may be dynamic.  Check again in a week or so and see if the IP is still the same.  If it is you may well be static.

Most ISPs charge extra for a static IP address though.

Comment: Or you could just log into your router setup page and see how it's configured.

Comment: That wouldn't tell you if it was static or not - even assigned by DHCP (or LCP or whatever) it can still be static.

Answer (score 3):

Open a CMD window and type ipconfig/release then type ipconfig and see if you have an IP.

Or through the GUI you can go to Control Panel>Network and Sharing Center, on the left pane select: "change adapter settings", right click your adapter and click Properties, select: "Internet Protocol Version 4" and hit the properties button. If "Obtain IP Address Automatically" is checked then you are getting your IP via DHCP if it is static you will see it filled out in the boxes below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you set your IP address in any way via CMD or the network settings you have a static IP. Otherwise, you have an IP assigned by DHCP.

Comment: The Network Settings is the GUI. Excuse me for my terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the answer in the Registry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{here-goes-the-GUID-of-the-NIC}
-> EnableDHCP
```

1 means ON, 0 means OFF

You need to know the GUID of your NIC, of course. Your machine might have more than just one NIC.

Comment: It's still possible that at the time of IP-assigning, it was static/dhcp & registry was changed later... So this is not exactly reliable. But yes, at boot time, it would take static/dhcp based on this registry...